# Проблема с выводом данных в текстовый файл C++

Tags: c++, fstream, winhttp

Пытаюсь разобраться с библиотекой winHTTP.h, для этого скопировал код с https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winhttp/winhttp-sessions-overview
Хочу данные из pszOutBuffer вывести в текстовый файл, но содержимое отличается от того что выводится в консоль.

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <winhttp.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

#pragma comment(lib, "winhttp.lib")

using namespace std;

int main() {

    DWORD dwSize = 0;
    DWORD dwDownloaded = 0;
    LPSTR pszOutBuffer;
    BOOL  bResults = FALSE;
    HINTERNET  hSession = NULL,
        hConnect = NULL,
        hRequest = NULL;

    // Use WinHttpOpen to obtain a session handle.
    hSession = WinHttpOpen(L"WinHTTP Example/1.0",
        WINHTTP_ACCESS_TYPE_DEFAULT_PROXY,
        WINHTTP_NO_PROXY_NAME,
        WINHTTP_NO_PROXY_BYPASS, 0);

    // Specify an HTTP server.
    if (hSession)
        hConnect = WinHttpConnect(hSession, L"www.microsoft.com",
            INTERNET_DEFAULT_HTTPS_PORT, 0);

    // Create an HTTP request handle.
    if (hConnect)
        hRequest = WinHttpOpenRequest(hConnect, L"GET", L"/en-us/",
            NULL, WINHTTP_NO_REFERER,
            WINHTTP_DEFAULT_ACCEPT_TYPES,
            WINHTTP_FLAG_SECURE);

    // Send a request.
    if (hRequest)
        bResults = WinHttpSendRequest(hRequest,
            WINHTTP_NO_ADDITIONAL_HEADERS, 0,
            WINHTTP_NO_REQUEST_DATA, 0,
            0, 0);


    // End the request.
    if (bResults)
        bResults = WinHttpReceiveResponse(hRequest, NULL);

    // Keep checking for data until there is nothing left.
    if (bResults)
    {
        do
        {
            // Check for available data.
            dwSize = 0;
            if (!WinHttpQueryDataAvailable(hRequest, &dwSize))
                printf("Error %u in WinHttpQueryDataAvailable.\n",
                    GetLastError());

            //cout << "dwSize = " << dwSize << endl;

            // Allocate space for the buffer.
            pszOutBuffer = new char[dwSize + 1];
            if (!pszOutBuffer)
            {
                printf("Out of memory\n");
                dwSize = 0;
            }
            else
            {
                // Read the data.
                ZeroMemory(pszOutBuffer, dwSize + 1);

                if (!WinHttpReadData(hRequest, (LPVOID)pszOutBuffer,
                    dwSize, &dwDownloaded))
                    printf("Error %u in WinHttpReadData.\n", GetLastError());
                else {
                    //printf("%s", pszOutBuffer);
                    fstream fout("output.txt");
                    if (fout.is_open()) {
                        cout << pszOutBuffer;
                        
                        fout << pszOutBuffer;
                        fout.close();
                    }
                    else {
                        cout << "File error\n";
                    }
                    
                }

                // Free the memory allocated to the buffer.
                delete[] pszOutBuffer;
            }
        } while (dwSize > 0);
    }
   // cout << "dwDownloaded = " << dwDownloaded << endl;

    // Report any errors.
    if (!bResults)
        printf("Error %d has occurred.\n", GetLastError());

    // Close any open handles.
    if (hRequest) WinHttpCloseHandle(hRequest);
    if (hConnect) WinHttpCloseHandle(hConnect);
    if (hSession) WinHttpCloseHandle(hSession);

    return 0;
}
```

Вывод в текстовый файл:

```
this).attr("id",r);t++})},4e3);function t(t){var i=t,t=i.find(".dropdown-list").val(),s=i.find(".dropdown-list  option:selected").data("btntext"),c=i.find(".dropdown-list  option:selected").data("arialabel"),e=i.find("select").val(),h=i.find(".dropdown-list  option:selected").data("btnarialabel"),o,r,u,f;e=="0"||e==null?(o=n(".c-select-menu").val(),n(".c-select-menu").find("button").attr("aria-label",o),i.next(".cta-link-btn").css("display","none")):(i.next(".cta-link-btn").css("display","inline-block"),i.next(".cta-link-btn").attr("href",t),i.next(".cta-link-btn").attr("aria-label",h),i.next(".cta-link-btn").find("span").html(s),r="",n(".c-select-menu > ul > li").each(function(){return r=n(this).find("span[aria-selected=true]").text(),r!=""?!1:void 0}),u=n(".c-select-menu").find("button").text(),u==r&&(n(".dropdown-list option:contains("+u+")").attr("selected","true"),f=n(".dropdown-list option:selected").data("arialabel"),n(".dropdown-list").attr("aria-label",f),n(".c-select-menu").find("button").attr("aria-label",f)))}}});location.href.toLowerCase().indexOf("rushmore")>0&&require(["jqReady!","deferExec!"],function(n){n("#headerRegion").find(".c-logo").attr("href","/en-us/rushmore/store");n("#cli_shellHeaderSearchInput").attr("placeholder","Search Microsoft Store");n("#border-generated-select-menu-trigger").text(n("#border-generated-select-menu-trigger ~ul li:first span p").html())});require(["platform"],function(){var n=setTimeout(function(){require.defined("multi-slide-carousel")&&(clearTimeout(n),n=null,require(["multi-slide-carousel"],function(n){n&&n.MultiSlideCarousel&&(n.MultiSlideCarousel.prototype.setAutoPlayInterval=function(){var n=this;this.clearAutoPlayTimers&&this.clearAutoPlayTimers();autoPlayIntervalDuration=Math.max(2e3,parseInt(n.carouselElement&&n.carouselElement.getAttribute("data-js-interval"),10)||6e3);this.autoPlayTimer=setTimeout(function(){n.setActiveSlide&&n.setActiveSlide(n.activeIndex+1,!1)},autoPlayIntervalDuration)})}))},500)})</script>



        <script>

            if (window.addEventListener) {

                window.addEventListener("load", createSilentAuthFrame, false);

            } else if (window.attachEvent) {

                window.attachEvent("onload", createSilentAuthFrame);

            } else {

                window.onload = createSilentAuthFrame;

            }



            function InvokeSSOFrame(src) {

                var i = document.createElement("iframe");

                i.src = src;

                i.setAttribute("width", "0");

                i.setAttribute("height", "0");

                i.setAttribute("border", "0");

                i.setAttribute("frameborder", "0");

                i.setAttribute("style", "display: none");

                i.style = "display: none";

                document.body.appendChild(i);

            }



            function RefreshRemoteSSOSession(isUserAuthenticatedApi, silentPassport) {

                require(['jqReady!'], function ($) {

                    $.ajax(isUserAuthenticatedApi, {

                        type: "GET",

                        contentType: "text/plain",

                        xhrFields: {

                            withCredentials: true

                        },

                        crossDomain: true,

                        success: function (data) {

                            if (data.Status !== "Authenticated") {

                                InvokeSSOFrame(silentPassport);

                            }

                        }

                    });

                });

            }



            function createSilentAuthFrame() {

                var SSOCookieName = "ONERFSSO";

                if (document.cookie.indexOf(SSOCookieName) === -1) {

                    if ("False" === "True" && 1 !== 0) {

                            RefreshRemoteSSOSession("https://account.xbox.com/en-us/mscomhp/onerf/IsUserAuthenticated", "https://account.xbox.com/en-us/mscomhp/onerf/MeSilentPassport");

                    }

                    else {

                        InvokeSSOFrame("https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/mscomhp/onerf/MeSilentPassport");

                    }

                    document.cookie = SSOCookieName + "=1";

                }

            }



        </script>



    

</body>

</html>







mpany_Security_nav","id":"n8c6c1c1m1r1a3","sN":8,"aN":"c6c1c1m1r1a3"}'>Security</a>

                            </li>



                        </ul>

                        

                    </div>

                </div>

        </nav>

    <div class="c-uhff-base">

                <a id="locale-picker-link" aria-label="Content Language Selector. Currently set to English (United States)" class="c-uhff-link c-uhff-lang-selector c-glyph glyph-world" href="https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/locale?absoluteReturnUrl=https%3a%2f%2fwww.microsoft.com%2fen-us%2f" data-m='{"cN":"locale_picker(US)_nav","id":"n7c1c1m1r1a3","sN":7,"aN":"c1c1m1r1a3"}'>English (United States)</a>



        <nav aria-label="Microsoft corporate links">

            <ul class="c-list f-bare" data-m='{"cN":"Corp links_cont","cT":"Container","id":"c8c1c1m1r1a3","sN":8,"aN":"c1c1m1r1a3"}'>

                                <li  id="c-uhff-footer_sitemap">

                    <a class="c-uhff-link" href="https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/sitemap1.aspx" data-mscc-ic="false" data-m='{"cN":"Footer_Sitemap_nav","id":"n1c8c1c1m1r1a3","sN":1,"aN":"c8c1c1m1r1a3"}'>Sitemap</a>

                </li>

                <li  id="c-uhff-footer_contactus">

                    <a class="c-uhff-link" href="https://support.microsoft.com/contactus" data-mscc-ic="false" data-m='{"cN":"Footer_ContactUs_nav","id":"n2c8c1c1m1r1a3","sN":2,"aN":"c8c1c1m1r1a3"}'>Contact Microsoft</a>

                </li>

                <li  id="c-uhff-footer_privacyandcookies">

                    <a class="c-uhff-link" href="https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=521839" data-mscc-ic="false" data-m='{"cN":"Footer_PrivacyandCookies_nav","id":"n3c8c1c1m1r1a3","sN":3,"aN":"c8c1c1m1r1a3"}'>Privacy </a>

                </li>

                <li class=" x-hidden" id="c-uhff-footer_managecookies">

                    <a class="c-uhff-link" href="#" data-mscc-ic="false" data-m='{"cN":"Footer_ManageCookies_nav","id":"n4c8c1c1m1r1a3","sN":4,"aN":"c8c1c1m1r1a3"}'>Manage cookies</a>

                </li>

                <li  id="c-uhff-footer_termsofuse">

                    <a class="c-uhff-link" href="https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=206977" data-mscc-ic="false" data-m='{"cN":"Footer_TermsOfUse_nav","id":"n5c8c1c1m1r1a3","sN":5,"aN":"c8c1c1m1r1a3"}'>Terms of use</a>

                </li>

                <li  id="c-uhff-footer_trademarks">

                    <a class="c-uhff-link" href="https://www.microsoft.com/trademarks" data-mscc-ic="false" data-m='{"cN":"Footer_Trademarks_nav","id":"n6c8c1c1m1r1a3","sN":6,"aN":"c8c1c1m1r1a3"}'>Trademarks</a>

                </li>

                <li  id="c-uhff-footer_safetyandeco">

                    <a class="c-uhff-link" href="https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/devices/safety-and-eco " data-mscc-ic="false" data-m='{"cN":"Footer_SafetyAndEco_nav","id":"n7c8c1c1m1r1a3","sN":7,"aN":"c8c1c1m1r1a3"}'>Safety &amp; eco</a>

                </li>

                <li  id="c-uhff-footer_aboutourads">

                    <a class="c-uhff-link" href="https://choice.microsoft.com" data-mscc-ic="false" data-m='{"cN":"Footer_AboutourAds_nav","id":"n8c8c1c1m1r1a3","sN":8,"aN":"c8c1c1m1r1a3"}'>About our ads</a>

                </li>



                <li>&#169; Microsoft 2022</li>

                

            </ul>

        </nav>

    </div>

    

</footer>









    </div>

        </div>



                    <script>window.performance && performance.mark && performance.mark("FooterAreaEnd")</script>

            <script>window.performance && performance.measure && performance.measure("FooterAreaDuration", "FooterAreaBegin", "FooterAreaEnd");</script>



        </div>

    

    

    <script>require(['deferExec!'],function(){require(['https://www.microsoft.com/library/sv      class="c-hyperlink quicklsнтитула" data-m='{"cN":
```

Comment: если оно отличается, может покажите разницу? но скорее всего в консоль выводили в 866 кодировке, а файл - cp1251/uft8

Comment: Там слишком много текста, я попробую сохранить в 2 текстовых файла, если же не получится, скопирую все сюда

Comment: текст весь выкладывать не нужно. Можно даже словами описать, что там не так

Comment: Слишком много символом, не могу вставить вывод, можно ли как-то текстовый файл залить в вопрос?

Comment: Я выложил то что у меня выводится в txt, похоже на то что выводит лишь часть данных, а в консоль выводится вся html-разметка

Comment: Я думал, что проблема в том, что переменная LPSTR pszOutBuffer не просто string и дело в этом, но присваивая string str = pszOutBuffer; Я получал одинаковые данные, пробовал после выводить содержимое str в txt, но ничего не изменилось

Comment: у Вас данные приходят не одним куском, а несколько подходов. Для этого там есть цикл do-while. Внутри него Вы пишите в файл Вы открываете каждый раз по новому, чем удаляете предыдущие данные. Либо открывайте файл до цикла, либо открывайте на дозапись.

Comment: Благодарю, сейчас попробую изменить

Comment: Да, все работает, большое спасибо!